# Передача параметра в promise

Tags: javascript, promise

Хочу передать в promise параметр с другого файла. Но из-за асинхроности (как мне кажется) выдаёт неверный ответ.

```
var promise_get_permissions = function (user_id_current) {
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        console.log(user_id_current);
        var result_array = [];

        connection.UserRoles
            .findAndCountAll({
                where: {
                    userId: user_id_current
                }
            })
            .then(function (result) {
                var role_id_current;
                for (var i = result.count - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    role_id_current = result.rows[i].dataValues["roleId"];

                    connection.RolePermissions
                        .findAndCountAll({
                            where: {
                                roleId: role_id_current
                            }
                        })
                        .then(function (result) {
                            var permission_id_current;
                            //console.log("permissions result:", result);
                            for (var i = result.count - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                                permission_id_current = result.rows[i].dataValues["permissionId"];

                                connection.Permissions
                                    .findById(permission_id_current)
                                    .then(function (result) {
                                        result_array.push(result.dataValues["code"]);
                                    })
                            }
                        })
                        .then(function () {
                            unique(result_array);
                        });
                }
            })
            .then(function () {
                unique(result_array);
                resolve(result_array);
            })
});
};
```

Вызываю код, который выше, здесь:

```
func_auth.promise_get_permissions(request.user)
    .then(function (result) {
        console.log(result);
        for (var i = result.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            get_permissions_array[result[i]] = true;
            // console.log(get_permissions_array[result[i]]);
        }
        console.log(get_permissions_array);
    })
    .then(function(){
        response.render("main.hbs",{
            is_auth_visible: request.isAuthenticated(),
            get_permissions: get_permissions_array
        });
    })
```

но в итоге `result` пустой, а в нём должны быть`code`ы
Укажите на ошибку или предложите альтернативный вариант.
Заранее спасибо!

И еще вопрос! Можно ли заставить ждать пока сработают все `then`ы?

Comment: Проверьте каскад промисов, какой то then вызывается не в том порядке.

Comment: я пробовал не оборачивать promise в функцию и вызывать как промис, а не как функции. В таком случае всё работает нормально. Но потом мне нужно было передать параметр и ничего не меняя я решил обернуть promise в функцию. И эта функция стала выдавать не верный ответ.

Comment: То есть тот `then`, где я заполняю массив `result_array`, не успевает сработать перед `resolve`. Сначала происходит `resolve`, потом этот `then`

Comment: да, нужно это проверить

Comment: законсольте в then (во всех) вашу переменную. И проверьте последовательность

Comment: проверил. Происходит что-то на подобии "обхода в ширину". То есть не проходит в глубь все `then`ы, а сначала идёт по внешним.
Сначала первый этаж `then`ов потом второй и так далее

Comment: Мне кажется у вас много лишних промисов. Там где unique(result_array); думаю можно их сократить и вставить в предыдущие промисы

Comment: то есть, там где у Вас вызывается второй раз then переместить в первый then

Comment: а зачем вообще `return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {` если функция `findAndCountAll` судя по всему уже возвращает Promise

Comment: эта функция вызывается с параметром. А если сначала сделать все операции, а потом `return`, то из-за асинхронности сначала будет `return`, потом уже все остальное.
Возможно я чего-то не знаю. За это прошу прощения

Comment: что делает функция `unique`? они меняет переданный ей массив или возвращает новый?

Comment: меняет. Убирает повторяющиеся значения

Answer (score 1):

Для того, чтобы цепочка вычислений шла по порядку, нужно чтобы каждый обработчик `then` возвращал очередной Promise, который надо дождаться.

В приведенном коде в нескольких местах асинхронная функция просто запускается и нигде не отслеживается когда она закончится.

Например:

```
connection.RolePermissions
    .findAndCountAll(...)

...
connection.Permissions
    .findById(permission_id_current)
```

---

Вместо этого, нужно возвращать Promise, которые получены из этих функций.

В случае, когда операции выполняются в цикле, и каждая возвращает Promise, результаты можно собрать в массив и для ожидания окончания всех использовать [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

В итоге может код может выглядеть так:

```
var promise_get_permissions = function (user_id_current) {
    console.log(user_id_current);

    return connection.UserRoles
        .findAndCountAll({
            where: {
                userId: user_id_current
            }
        })
        .then(function (userRole) {
            var role_id_current;
            var rolePermissions = [];
            for (var i = userRole.count - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                role_id_current = userRole.rows[i].dataValues["roleId"];

                rolePermissions.push(connection.RolePermissions
                    .findAndCountAll({
                        where: {
                            roleId: role_id_current
                        }
                    }));
            }
            return Promise.all(rolePermissions);
        })
        .then(function (rolePermissions) {

            return Promise.all(rolePermissions.map(rolePermission=>{
                var permissions = [];
                for (var i = rolePermission.count - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    var permission_id_current = rolePermission.rows[i].dataValues["permissionId"];

                    permissions.push(connection.Permissions.findById(permission_id_current));
                }
                return Promise.all(permissions);
            }));
        })
        .then(function(permissions){
            return permissions.reduce((acc,permission)=>acc.concat(
                permission.map(p=>p.dataValues["code"])
            ),[]);
        })
        .then(function(resul){
            unique(result);
            return result;
        })
};
```

Можно обратить внимание, что теперь нет вложенных `then` и все выполняется последовательно.